# Combine lines in the diagram where there are missing values

Tags: looker-studio

It is necessary to combine lines in the diagram where there are missing values.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGOl3.png)

In the settings of the chart parameter, I don’t find the option to connect lines if there is no value. Perhaps you need to use a different chart type?